# Use xpath (libxml2) in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath, libxml2

I learned the libxml2 from http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html
Trying to parsing following html using libxml2:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1><a href="#">Content <em>1</em> <em>2</em></a></h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get all content in h1 without detecting all child?
if I use

```
//div/h1/a
```

I only get "Content"

If I use

```
//div/h1/a/descendant-or-self::*
```

I only got the content in

Is there a way to get "Content 1 2"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `//div/h1/a/descendant-or-self::*/text()`.

Comment: Hi Michael, text() does help selecting all text, but it breaks into 3 items "content" "1" "2", is there a solution? Thanks

Comment: There is no other solution. XPath will **always** return a nodeset on such operations. You have to concat it unless you have XPath 2.0 which allows you to say `string-join(//div/h1/a/descendant-or-self::*/text(),'')` and it will return one string. Since `libxml2` does not support XPath you have to follow the first approach.

Comment: The last sentence should read: Since `libxml2` does not support XPath *2.0* you have to follow the first approach.